# WPF ScrollViewer with webview2 Content Overlap other elements

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer, overlapping, webview2

```xml
<Window x:Class="wpfsamples.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" 
                WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowState="Normal"        
        >
    <Border CornerRadius="8" Padding="0" Width="1000" Height="800" x:Name="MainBorder">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="LightYellow"></SolidColorBrush>
        </Border.Background>

        <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="52"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Border Background="#242424" CornerRadius="6" Margin="47,10" Width="282" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock LineHeight="16" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="SF Pro Text" FontWeight="DemiBold" Text="Test Header" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="WhiteSmoke"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>



            <!--display the content panel-->
            <Border Background="#242424" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1">
                <ScrollViewer                    
                      x:Name="scrollviewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <WrapPanel Background="Black" Margin="8" x:Name="panel">
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="White" Width="300" Margin="20" Height="300">
                            <wv2:WebView2 Source="https://google.com"></wv2:WebView2>
                        </Border>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>

            <!--display the toolbar-->
            <Border Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ToolbarBorder" Background="Black" CornerRadius="0,0,8,8" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="0">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="toolbar" ShowGridLines="False" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button  Name="btn_showdevicelist" Foreground="White" Content="Start" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="MyButton"  Background="Black" Width="64"  Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  >

                    </Button>


                </Grid>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

this is the entire code for the window, you can copy and run it, when i have many elements show in the border embed with webview2  and then when i scroll vertically, the content in the wrapper panel overlap the bottom toolbar ..  but if i comment out the webview2, then there will be no issue. how to avoid this ?

[the screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR0ht.png)

Comment: Can you please include the entire page, or at least the element containing the two borders? That information is essential for diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @MichalDiviš thanks , i added the entire code capture in the description.  I am not using windows style window, i set window style to none , i used the border as the entire window

Comment: You really need to provide some XAML which we can copy paste and run the application in our VS. For example, I don't see why the ScrollViewer would scroll anything, since the WrapPanel is empty. You also need to provide the complete Grid definition holding the borders, because the Grid might be responsible for the overlap.

Comment: @PeterHuber i will provide , thanks

Comment: @PeterHuber   i changed the description and copied the full code, you can run in your local. thanks

Comment: I could run your code when commenting out WebView2, which I did not want to install on my PC. I hope somebody else can help. However I wonder if the 300 x 300 pixel border is too small for the browser to display ? Does it work if you host only 1, but big WebView2 ? If you use 2 WebView2  ? Just a guess. It seems to me you do not need to put the WebView2 into a border. WebView2 inherits from FrameworkElement and has therefore properties like Width, Margin, Height. Do you get also the problem when you use a StackPanel instead a WrapPanel ?

Comment: @PeterHuber  i have to use wrapperPanel and display many web pages within webview2 ... i did some search , looks like the webbrowser or webview2 is designed to be at the top of the UI element..

Comment: This issue seems to be `WebView2` related. If you replace the `WebView2` with an other control (like Border), the overlapping goes away. I've found an [issue in the WebView2 feedback repo related to this](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/286)

Answer (score 1):

you have the classic and well known Airspace issue. Known for more than 10 years. Lots to read on it as for example in 2011 [M$ had a good attempt to fix it](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-8-no-more-airspace-problems-integrating-wpf-with-win32/) and failed and gave up. It is unofficially on the "won't fix" list but you will never get an engineer to admit it. They now intentionally simply code for example the Webview2 by just making a winforms version and then wrapping that into a WPF using winformshost.

There are so many articles and things on it [just do a Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf%20airspace%20issue&oq=wpf%20airspace%20issue&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57.7498j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

As for your problem, I think you will never find a solution. No native WPF element or control will ever cover the Webview2. If for example the WPF has its own HWND like a context menu, tooltip or more generally a Popup/Window THEN it will go over the top.

You need to rethink your idea if you want to use WebView2

Of course the one true [WPF implementation is CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) which "renders" the page into native WPF and you can do exactly what you want.